# Remotely execute commands but still have control of the host

Tags: compiling, cluster, parallelism

I have a few Linux machines laying around and I wanted to make a cluster computer network. There will be 1 monitor that would be for the controller. The controller would execute a script that would perform a task and split the load onto the computers.

Lets say I have 4 computers that are all connected to the controller. I wanted to compile a program using GCC but I wanted to split the work 3 ways. How would I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the full answer to this takes an entire semester at most colleges that teach it.  So, a complete answer here would be too long...

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title of the question to mention distributed compilation, if that's what you specifically want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making a [Beowulf Cluster](https://www.linux.com/blog/building-beowulf-cluster-just-13-steps).  You set up one host as a master and the rest as nodes.  It's been done in the past by others, including NASA as the [wikipedia entry on Beowulf Cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster) says.

Building your own cluster computer farm might cost more in power than you'd gain in compute resources.

I have not tried this myself, but I've always wanted to give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

`distcc` can be used to compile code on multiple machines.

From the debian `distcc` package info:

> Package: distcc
>
> Description-en: simple distributed compiler client and
>   server
>
> `distcc` is a program to distribute compilation of `C` or `C++` code across several machines on a network. `distcc` should always generate the same results as a local compile, is simple to install and use, and is often significantly faster than a local compile.  `distcc` does not require all  machines to share a filesystem, have synchronized clocks, or to have the same libraries or header files installed.
>
> Homepage: http://distcc.org/

For other tasks, it's a lot more complicated than a script to "perform a task and split the load onto the computers".  You'll need to use a scheduler (e.g. [slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com) or [torque](http://www.clusterresources.com/pages/products/torque/) - both packaged for debian and most other distros.  My preference is for `slurm`).

In other words, turn your collection of linux machines into a cluster.  This is not particularly difficult to do, but it is a fair amount of work and requires a good deal of reading and understanding (and much of what you read will be relevant to large HPC clusters at universities or research labs, but not really relevant to a small home cluster).

Note that if you want to be able to run programs that spread the workload over multiple machines in the cluster simultaneously, they'll have to:

1. be performing a job that is suitable for being run in parallel (e.g. work can be split into small chunks that can be processed separately, with the results combined later)
2. have shared access to required resources (e.g. an NFS server to read and write files)

AND either:

3. have to be written specifically to communicate with other instances running on other nodes in the cluster (e.g. by using an [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) library such as [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/))

OR

4. have a master controlling process that does the communication and control, which is what `distcc` does.

Comment: BTW, there are many existing open-source (and proprietary) programs written to use MPI.  If you're interested in computational science in any way, you can see lists of programs for various scientific and academic fields at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience - most of these should be available for other distros to (e.g. Scientific Linux), and there are also many that aren't (yet) packaged for debian.

Comment: also btw, maths & stats software like octave and R also have MPI libs available.  as do programming languages like C, C++, FORTRAN, perl, python, and many more.